# combine multiple fields with the same name using regexp

Tags: regex, xslt

I have multiple fields with the same name "item" inside json object, how can I combine their values under one field (as an array) using **regex**

**sample input:**
`{"item":"A","item":"B","item":"C"}`

**expected output:**
`"item": ["A","B","C"]`

note that we could have more than 3 items on above sample

I have tried `{"item":"(.*?)","item":"(.*?)","item":"(.*?)"}` but here I'm limited with 3 items, I need something to work for any number of items.

Thanks

Comment: Parsing JSON or any other structured language using regex is almost never a good idea. This is especially true when the input has a dynamic shape, for example any number of items in your example. Furthermore, the snippet you posted is not valid JSON as it has duplicate keys.

Comment: that is my problem, I need to fix the JSON before parsing it

Comment: In that case I would opt for a pattern similar to what you have, but with a single match and using the global modifier to find all matching items. Like: `"item":\s*"(.*?)"` with "g" flag.

Comment: If I used that, and replace it with ``Item:["$1"]`` ... I got three separate items ``{Item:["A"],Item:["B"],Item:["C"]}``

Comment: what programming language are you using? You can't do this in pure regex.

Comment: I'm using XSL stylesheet

Comment: I'm not sure how you would do it with XSL, but the RegEx for something like that, could be `(?:"item":"([^"]+)")+`

Answer (score 0):

The conversion you want can be performed quite easily in XSLT 2.0 or higher using:

```
    <xsl:text>"item": [</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="for $i in tokenize(translate($input, '{}', ''), ',') return substring-after($i, ':')" separator=","/>
    <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
```

Demo: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiorv1e

---

Of course, if your ultimate goal is to parse the input in order to use its values, then it's not necessary to put it back as JSON.